# Integrate with `Max` and `Min` under assumptions runs forever

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve an integral under certain conditions on the parameters. The following is my code.

```
v1 = (1 - r1) x + r1 y;
i1 = Integrate[(d - (v1 - c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, d}, {y, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x, Min[Max[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s]}] + Integrate[(d - (v1 - q c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, s}, {y, 0, Max[0, Min[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x]]}];
FullSimplify[Integrate[Max[v1 - (1 + i1) d], {x, 0, s}, {y, Min[Max[((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s], s}], Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s]
```

It looks somehow complicated, but the idea is straightforward. But it is funning forever.

[Edit]: I Applied user64494's approach and the code is as follows which is also running forever.

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
v1 = (1 - r1) x + r1 y; 
i1 = Integrate[(d - (v1 - c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, d}, {y, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x, Min[Max[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s] // PiecewiseExpand}, Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s, GenerateConditions -> False] + Integrate[(d - (v1 - q c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, s}, {y, 0, Max[0, Min[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x]] // PiecewiseExpand}, Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s, GenerateConditions -> False];
Integrate[Max[v1 - (1 + i1) d], {x, 0, s}, {y, Min[Max[((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s], s // PiecewiseExpand}, Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

Comment: `FullSimplify[Integrate[...]]` means every time `FullSimplify` makes a change in the integral, Mathematica tries to calculate the integral again. Simplify the integrand, or simplify the result assuming `Integrate` evaluates to an answer. Since `i1` does not evaluate to an answer, it makes things even worse. The main point I'm trying to make I guess is to do the simplifications independently of the integrals; and check the integrals before simplifying.

Comment: `Assumptions` might help, if there are any constraints on your parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

```
v1 = (1 - r1) x + r1 y;
i1 = Integrate[(d - (v1 - c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, d}, {y, 
d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x, Min[Max[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s]//PiecewiseExpand},
Assumptions ->     0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s, 
GenerateConditions -> False] +  Integrate[(d - (v1 - q c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, s}, {y, 0, 
Max[0, Min[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x]] // 
 PiecewiseExpand },   Assumptions ->  0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 &&
 2 d < s,  GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `1/6*(d*(-3*d - 6*c*q + 4*d*r1 + 6*c*q*r1))/((-1 + r1)^2*s^2) +  Piecewise[{{(d*(-1 + 2*r1)*(-3*c - d + 3*c*r1 + 2*d*r1))/ (6*(-1 + r1)^2*r1*s^2), Inequality[0, Less, d, Less, 1] &&  Inequality[0, Less, r1, Less, 1/2] && d/r1 - s <= 0}},  (-6*c*d^2 - 3*d^3 + 6*c*d^2*r1 + 4*d^3*r1 + 6*c*d*s + 3*d^2*s -  6*c*d*r1*s - 3*d^2*r1*s - 3*c*r1*s^2 - 3*d*r1*s^2 + 3*c*r1^2*s^2 +  3*d*r1^2*s^2 + r1^2*s^3 - r1^3*s^3)/(6*d*(-1 + r1)^2*s^2)]`B

in short time. I think the question is art for art's sake.

Addition. The OP also asked about

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Max[v1 - (1 + i1) d], {x, 0, s}, {y, Min[Max[((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s], s}], Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s]
```

which runs forever. We start from

```
Max[v1 - (1 + i1) d] // PiecewiseExpand
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{6 c d^2 q-6 c d^2+6 c d s-3 c \text{r1} s^2+3 d^2 s-9 d \text{r1}
>    s^2+6 d s^2+\text{r1}^2 s^3-6 \text{r1}^2 s^2 x+6 \text{r1}^2 s^2 y+12
>    \text{r1} s^2 x-6 \text{r1} s^2 y-6 s^2 x}{6 (\text{r1}-1) s^2} &
>    d\geq 1\lor d\leq 0\lor \text{r1}\geq \frac{1}{2}\lor \text{r1}\leq
>    0\lor \frac{d}{\text{r1}}-s>0 \\
>  \frac{6 c d^2 q \text{r1}-6 c d^2 \text{r1}+3 c d^2+d^3-6 d \text{r1}^2
>    s^2+6 d \text{r1} s^2-6 \text{r1}^3 s^2 x+6 \text{r1}^3 s^2 y+12
>    \text{r1}^2 s^2 x-6 \text{r1}^2 s^2 y-6 \text{r1} s^2 x}{6
>    (\text{r1}-1) \text{r1} s^2} & \text{True}
> \end{cases} $$

As we see, there are two cases. The condition of the first case `d >= 1 || d <= 0 || r1 >= 1/2 || r1 <= 0 || d/r1 - s > 0` is, in fact, the negation of the assumptions `0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d < s`. However, we consider it for completeness. The expression `Min[Max[((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s]` says that in the general case `((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x>=0` and `((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x <= s` so we write down these as conditions. Now

```
Integrate[ 1/(6 (-1 + r1) s^2) (c (6 d^2 (-1 + q) + 6 d s - 3 r1 s^2) + 
s (3 d^2 + d (6 - 9 r1) s + 
   s (-6 x + 6 r1 (2 x - y) + r1^2 (s - 6 x + 6 y)))), {x, 0, s}, 
{y, ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, s}, 
 Assumptions ->  d >= 1 || d <= 0 || 2 r1 >= 1 || r1 <= 0 || 
   d/r1 > s && ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x > 
 0 && ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x < s, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `(1/(72 (-1 +  r1)^2 r1 s^3))(9 c^2 (2 d^2 (-1 + q) + 2 d s - r1 s^2)^2 +  6 c s (2 d^2 (-1 + q) + 2 d s - r1 s^2) (3 d^2 +  d (6 - 9 r1) s + (-3 + 4 r1^2) s^2) +  s^2 (9 d^4 + 18 d^3 (2 - 3 r1) s +  3 d^2 (6 + r1 (-36 + 35 r1)) s^2 -  6 d (-2 + 3 r1) (-3 + 4 r1^2) s^3 + (12 +  r1 (-12 + r1 (-6 + r1 (-12 + 19 r1)))) s^4))`

Now we turn to the second case.

```
Integrate[ Simplify[(1/(6 (-1 + r1) r1 s^2)) (3 c d^2 + d^3 - 6 c d^2 r1 +    6 c d^2 q r1 + 6 d r1 s^2 - 6 d r1^2 s^2 - 6 r1 s^2 x + 
 12 r1^2 s^2 x - 6 r1^3 s^2 x - 6 r1^2 s^2 y + 6 r1^3 s^2 y)], {x, 0, s}, {y, ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, s}, 
Assumptions ->  0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 
   2 d < s && ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x > 
0 && ((1 + i1) d)/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x < s, GenerateConditions -> False];
```

The result is useless in view of

```
LeafCount[%]
```

> `955`

I repeat all tht is art for art's sake. The right way is to evaluate all the parameters before integrating.

Comment: Thanks, user64494, but the last (third) line of my original code is missing. Can you please help once more on this?

Comment: @ppp: See addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach with additional Assumptions and traced Simplify gives a simple result

```
v1 = (1 - r1) x + r1 y;
i1 = Integrate[(d - (v1 - c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, d}, {y,d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x,Min[Max[d/r1 - (1 - r1)/r1 x, 0], s]}, 
Assumptions -> 0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2d < s] 
+ 
Integrate[(d - (v1 - q c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, s}, {y, 0,Max[0, Min[d/r1- (1 - r1)/r1 x, d/(1 - r1) - r1/(1 - r1) x]]}, 
Assumptions ->0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d< s]

//Simplify[#,0 < d < 1 && 0 < c < 1 && q > 1 && 0 < r1 < 1/2 && 2 d< s] &
```

$\begin{cases}
 -\frac{d (c (6 (q-1) \text{r1}+3)+d)}{6 (\text{r1}-1) \text{r1} s^2} &
   d\leq \text{r1} s \\
 \frac{c \left(-6 d^2 (q-1)-6 d s+3 \text{r1} s^2\right)-s \left(3 d^2-3 d
   \text{r1} s+\text{r1}^2 s^2\right)}{6 d (\text{r1}-1) s^2} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$

Hope it helps!